# Choropleth raster to polygons with values

Tags: arcpy, raster, polygon

I'm trying to turn a PNG that looks like this to a shapefile with polygons that keep the categories marked by the colors on the map.

[image]

I have several maps to process, so manually tracing the polygons is not a valid option.

I tried to do this with `arcpy.RasterToPolygon`, [from here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm) :

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/data"
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion("zone", "c:/output/zones.shp", "NO_SIMPLIFY",
                                  "VALUE")
```

In this case "zone" is the input PNG, this layer is already georeferenced to its actual location. zones.shp is the filename where I want to store the new features.

I get the following error:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<string>", line 5, in <module>   
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 337, in RasterToPolygon     
raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 010151: No features found in c:\gis\output\control_test.shp. 
Possible empty feature class. Failed to execute (RasterToPolygon).
```

Is it possible to fix this error or to use another function to get to my goal?

I have the original PNG as an SVG with vector drawn polygons if that helps.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your inputs and/or provide a code snippet?

Comment: @GeoSharp sure, I made edits to the question to have more context on the inputs

Comment: It would be more helpful if you showed your code rather than copying the snippet from the documentation...

Comment: @GeoSharp I literally used the same code as the snippet, I don't know what other changes I can do to it to make it work

Comment: @Paul Thanks! How can I execute the tool from desktop? If I only use the PNG, how will I be able to add the georeferencing to it?

Comment: @buzoherbert, if your png has a world file associated with it, then the tool should honor it. When you add your PNG to Desktop, does it display where it should?

Comment: @Paul Thanks for your comments and answer. The output I have works well, but it doesn't use the colors to add attributes to the files. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded your image (no coordinates of course) and ran the following:

```
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion("C:/temp/2baAg.png","in_memory/poly","NO_SIMPLIFY","Value")
```

Note the file extension on the image is required.

And here's the output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have the shapes now in ArcGIS, but the conversion didn't take into account the cloropeth categories on the original PNG. Is there a way to consider this?